Error : Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') Discord bot Discord.js V14
i just wanted that the bot if i interact with the button it will create a channel on the "ticket" category if there is no ticket category i verify if there is any category with the id that i needed and if not the bot create one
btw here is my code :
const { Client, IntentsBitField, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, Permissions } = require("discord.js");

const ChannelIDs = [
    "1194626191504703609", "1220403612157608017", "1214602084507459696",
    "1205122006975258624", "1194626176887566400", "1233790139671515196",
    "1233786987014651965", "1204022782149664788", "1259563299712929914",
    "1194626159607021578", "1194626093165064213", "1250802176444596265"
];

let ticketsCategoryID = null; // Variable to hold the category ID
let i = 0;
const prefix = "&";

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,

    ]
});

client.once("ready", async() => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is working!`);

    const guildId = "guild"; 
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

    if (!guild) {
        console.error(`Guild with ID ${guildId} not found.`);
        return;
    }

    let category = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY" && c.name === "tickets");

    if (!category) {
        category = await guild.channels.create("tickets", {
            type: "GUILD_CATEGORY",
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
                deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
            }]
        });

        ticketsCategoryID = category.id;
        console.log(`Tickets category ID: ${ticketsCategoryID}`);
    } else {
        ticketsCategoryID = category.id;
        console.log(`Found existing tickets category with ID: ${ticketsCategoryID}`);
    }
});

client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    if (message.content === prefix + 'setup' && ChannelIDs.includes(message.channel.id)) {
        await message.delete();

        const button = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('Open_Ticket')
                .setLabel('Open Ticket ️')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            );

        const embed = {
            color: 'GREEN',
            description: 'Click on the button to open a new ticket'
        };

        await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [button] });
    }
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async(interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton() || interaction.customId !== 'Open_Ticket') return;

    if (!ticketsCategoryID) {
        return interaction.reply({
            content: "Tickets category is not set up correctly. Please contact an admin.",
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }

    const guild = interaction.guild;
    const ticketCategory = guild.channels.cache.get(ticketsCategoryID);

    if (!ticketCategory) {
        return interaction.reply({
            content: "Tickets category not found. Please contact an admin.",
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }

    i += 1;
    const channelName = `channel-${i}`;

    await guild.channels.create(channelName, {
        type: "GUILD_TEXT",
        parent: ticketCategory.id,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: guild.roles.everyone,
                deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
            },
            {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
            }
        ]
    });

    await interaction.reply({ content: `Created channel: ${channelName}`, ephemeral: true });
});

const token = "token";
client.login(token);

and here is the entire error :
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\Alpha\Desktop\devlopment =)\bot jelly\src\index.js:43:36)
    at onceWrapper (events:634:26)
    at emit (events:519:28)
    at triggerClientReady (c:\Users\Alpha\Desktop\devlopment =)\bot jelly\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:388:17)
    at checkShardsReady (c:\Users\Alpha\Desktop\devlopment =)\bot jelly\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:371:10)
jelly\src\index.js:119:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)

tried to name the FLAGS to flags didn t work

you can manage permissions flags with this :
const { Client, IntentsBitField, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, PermissionFlagsBits} = require("discord.js");

category = await guild.channels.create("tickets", {
   type: "GUILD_CATEGORY",
   permissionOverwrites: [{
      id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
      deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
   }]
});

I hope this helps you!

The Permissions object doesn't have a FLAGS key when you try to read it from these two lines
deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
Try this
deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel]
allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel]
